# How can I convert an excel workbook with 6 different sheets to a sharepoint list?

Tags: excel, sharepoint-list

Should unify all the sheets into one giant list ? I would be great if there was some mechanism to combine the sheets into one entity but yet keep them separate within that entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could combine the sheets into the one giant list, upload it to SharePoint using "Import Spreadsheet" app , then use "Views" within the SharePoint list to separate the information based on type or whatever distinguishes one sheet from another. I'm not sure if this works or is too simplistic for you not knowing what the list consists of.

Comment: Thank you Molly. Will try the one giant list approach.